# Android 11 and the app directory that contains raw resource files

Tags: android, android-studio, directory

I am developing Android app that runs as test for Android 11. My app uses wave sound file saved in `res/raw directory`. The file is resided which directory when entire app is installed to Android 11 device? I think `Android/data/data/package_name` or `Android/data/user/0/package_name`, without rooting `Android/data/data` is not accessible. I think some app was not deleted fully and remaining file influences behaviour of my app, I would like to see the directory `res/raw` files are resided after installation.

If not, there are several other causes for my test. This time, can you tell me what directory res/raw files reside?

Comment: `Android/data/data/package_name or Android/data/user/0/package_name` Those are both impossible non existent paths.

Comment: No, it is possible. I am using Samsung SM-X200 and SM-T733, when accessing adb shell and run-as command, the latter is open. However, the former is not appearing any file commanders, so asked.

Comment: I think the information for this question is sensitive for security reason, so it is okay not to answer me, however, if possible, I would like to still ask.

Answer (score 0):

Files at design time in res\raw
of project directory become resources when the app is installed and runs.

Try with getResources() and so on.

Open an input stream to read them.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply for me ^^ However, I would like to access from Android adb shell, to check if there is file chrooted, permission check. I don't have information yet, so please teach me how to access from adb Android/data/data or Android/data/user/0/packagge_name and their subdirectories.

Comment: I don't want to root the device.... If rooted, it is accesible I guess, but no way that I want.

Comment: The paths you mentioned have nothing to do with res/raw. Unclear what is this about.

Comment: I know how we can access the file from Kotlin code, what I needed was adb access. File permission check purpose. It resolved by replacing the file to untroubled file and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue with my colleague, he has replaced sound file by reomote file push and memory injection turned off, now sound is well played without noise and my check to physical file permission is not necessary. Thank you for care for everyone.

Comment: He said my device was nearly hacked and the two methods turning off the result could resolve the problem and now sound is clear enough.

Comment: For more information why I asked this question was that the sound file included in my app sometimes artificiaily distorted output, so I would like to see the directory to make sure it was distorted or memory injection only.